# How can I add bunch of strings to list

Tags: python, python-2.7

My code looks like：

```
for line in fh:

    if not line.startswith("X-DSPAM-Confidence:"): 
        continue

    line = line.strip()
    line = line[20:]

    line.split() # I've got problem
```

I got bunch of lines and `line[20:]` prints lots of float numbers like

```
0.7565
0.7626
0.7556
0.7002
0.7615
0.7601
0.7605
0.6959
0.7606...and so on
```

I want to count these lines and extract the floating point values from each of the lines and compute the average of those values and produce an output as shown below.

How can I add this strings to one list, and get a sum and avg?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `line.split(" ")` will split the line based on the whitespaces and create a list that contains the floating points (however these will be handled as strings).

basically you could do something like the following 
`[for float(x) in line.split(" ")]` this will change the type to float for each entry in the list.

Next you could use the following operations to get the average and sum:

**average**

```
import numpy
numpy.mean([for float(x) in line.split(" ")])
```

**sum**

```
sum([for float(x) in line.split(" ")])
```

This should give a basic idea of how to handle the issue.

**EDIT:** It seems you updated your question, instead of a line containing multiple numbers it seems like each line contains a float now, is that correct? If that is the case you will simply need to read each line and add them to a list. You can then use the same methods I explained before.